# rails jquery ui datepicker

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, datepicker

I want to add the datepicker widget to one of my select fields.
I am currently using rails 3.2.13 with ruby 1.9.3.p325.
I also included the 'jquery_datepicker' gem, as well as 'jquery-rails' and 'jquery-ui-rails'

The form code looks as following.

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :datum %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :datum , :id => "datepicker" %>
  </div>
```

The included javascript is:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require select2
//= require_tree .


$ ->
  $("#practice_toolkeeper")
    .select2({
         allowClear: true,
         placeholder: 'Select an item'
    })
    .select2('val',$("#toolkeeper_value").val())    

$ ->
  $("#datepicker").datepicker()
```

which generate HTML

```
<div class="field">
  <label for="practice_datum">Datum</label><br />
  <input id="datepicker" name="practice[datum]" size="30" type="text" />
</div>
```

if you select the input field, nothing is happening

Comment: sorry but what is use of `$ ->` in code?? Or it just there for this question ?

Comment: I'm very new to jquery and coffescript, etc.. I don't know it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

```
$("datepicker").datepicker();
```

with

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
```

Missing `#` in selecotr. As `datepicker` is `id` of element. You need to use `#` in selector.

**UPDATE**

```
jQuery($)->
 $("#datepicker").datepicker();
 .....
```

This should work.

**Update 2**

Suppose you have following content in `sample.coffee` file -

```
jQuery ->
 $("#datepicker").datepicker();
```

You need to compile abouve file with following command -

```
coffee -c sample.coffee
```

This will then generate `js` file with following contents -

```
(function() {
  jQuery(function() {
    return $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  });

}).call(this);
```

If you are not familiar well with coffee script, go though http://coffeescript.org/#installation

Comment: ok I've changed that, but that had no effect, see my edit above

Comment: not working, but now in firebug I get following error: 

TypeError: jQuery(...).datepicker is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

return jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker();

Comment: now only the rror message has changed.. TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

return $("#datepicker").datepicker();

Comment: Can you post the output generated by coffee script ? the code you've mentioned will not run in browser but instead it'll generate javascript that you need to put inside page.

Comment: i don't know how to get the code, but thats the html include <script media="all" src="/assets/practices.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 2):

You missed the `#` to select element with id datepicker. It should be

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker()
```